# What is the exact renormalization regularization for divergent harmonic serise?

Tags: renormalization, regularization, harmonics

given the harmonic series

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+a} $$

what is the correct option for the regularization ?

a) $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+a}= -\Psi (a) $ Digamma function

b) $  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+a}= -\Psi(a)+\log a $

for $ a=1 $ the solution is the same $  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}= \gamma $

but for any other positive a? where can i find info on the Harmonci generalized series and physics?